# Get Golang to accept a token for GET authorization

Tags: go, get, http-headers, authorization, bearer-token

I cant seem to get my script to accept my bearer token. Here is my script:

```
func main(){

    url := "https://www.mywebsite.com"
    response, err := http.Get(url)   
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
        fmt.Print(err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    response.Header.Add("Authorization", os.ExpandEnv("$BEARER_TOKEN"))

    fmt.Println(response.Header.Get("authorization"))


    responseData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(responseData))
}
```

I did `fmt.Println(response.Header.Get("authorization"))` to see if it was accepting the token and it printed the token correctly, so im not sure why its not accepting it for the GET request.

Ive also tried `response.Header.Set` instead of `response.Header.Add` and it had the same outcome.

The response I get back when I run that script is:
`{"code":16,"message":"token not valid for running mode"}` but I know the token is correct because I tried it in a curl command and I got the output that I wanted

Comment: So you want to include "Authorization" in the request right?, I think you shouldn't use http.Get() because it fired the request as you called it. Make a http.NewRequest(), include the Authorization in the `request` header, not in the `response` header, and send it by using `http.Client{}.Do()` funtion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to use http.NewRequest() and set `request` Header Authorization

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    url := "https://www.mywebsite.com"

    client := http.Client{Timeout: 5 * time.Second}
    request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)

    request.Header.Set("Authorization", os.ExpandEnv("$BEARER_TOKEN"))
    request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json") // => your content-type

    response, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    responseData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(responseData))
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked, thanks!

Comment: Btw. Why use os.ExpandEnv?

Comment: @Volker

`ExpandEnv replaces ${var} or $var in the string according to the values
of the current environment variables. References to undefined
variables are replaced by the empty string`
// comment of os.ExpandEnv

Because he use $BEARER_TOKEN in the string, instead of using os.GetEnv()

Comment: @DavidYappeter I'm well aware of how os.ExpandEnv works and it is completely overkill here. os.Getenv("BEARER_TOKEN") is less to type, clearer and faster. Thus again: Why use os.ExpandEnv?

Comment: Because it is in his code. I only change the request part and keep others the same.